# In Core Foundation, do you have to access objects only using references?

Tags: core-foundation

I am trying to write a bit of Objective-C (which is new for me, my background is more C++), and wanted to create a CFString like this :

```
CFString myString;
```

When I try to build my project the following error :

```
"'CFString' undeclared" (first use in this function)
```

prevents from building. 
I thought I had just forgot to include the relevant header, but I cannot find which one to include. When I look into some sample code I never see "CFString" but rather "CFStringRef" objects, defined as

```
A reference to a CFString object.
typedef const struct __CFString *CFStringRef;
```

I started to suspect there is no such thing as a CFString that i can refer to in the code, but I feel I am wrong somewhere. Am I ?
Is it impossible to create CFStrings ? Is it specific to CFString or to all the structs in objective-c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFStringRef` is part of the Core Foundation library which is not ObjC but plain C. Core Foundation uses a runtime to create instances, this runtime will call callbacks to initialize the structs content and manages the instances memory.
This is why there is no `CFString` because you shouldn't create static instances on the stack but rather call the appropriate create function which will then ask the runtime for a new instance with everything already initialized for you. For `CFStringRef` this would be `CFStringCreate()`, see also: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/introCFStrings.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I also tried to create a c-style struct and to instantiate it as an object in a method of my objective-c class, and obtained the error message "Storage size of 'myObject' isn't known". Is it because of the necessity of relying on that runtime ? Would I have to dynamically allocate my struct to use it in my objective-c class ?

Comment: There are many functions to create a CFString; `CFStringCreate` is only one of them.

Comment: @wil: Please ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @Peter I started to write a new question but I found I cannot reproduce the bug today (I can use a struct normally), so I guess this separate problem is solved.